# ctr-click skim pdf world to corresponding line on vim latex editor

Tags: mac, vim, vim-latex

I am using vim latex on my mac to compile .tex files whose output pdf is shown on skim to visualize them. I would like to know if there is a way to couple the two programs in such a way that when perform a ctr click or double click on a world on the skim pdf it goes to the corresponding line on mac vim, like when you double click or ctrl click on the pdf on texmaker and send your cursor on the corresponding line on the editor page.

Comment: actually I had already saw it but I couldn't  figure out how to proceed in order to set-up the forward and backward research between vim and skim!

Comment: This could be potentially useful:

http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/forward-searching.html#enabling-searching